# Native Fullscreen JavaScript API toggle button

Tags: javascript, dom-events, fullscreen

I can't figure out how to modify the below code to include a toggle button. When in 'normal' mode the button would make the element go fullscreen and then change its function to go back to 'normal' state.

I've modified the code from [John Dyer's Native Fullscreen JavaScript API](http://johndyer.name/lab/fullscreenapi/) example:

```
var fsButton = document.getElementById('fsbutton'),
    fsElement = document.getElementById('specialstuff'),
    fsStatus = document.getElementById('fsstatus');


if (window.fullScreenApi.supportsFullScreen) {
    fsStatus.innerHTML = 'YES: Your browser supports FullScreen';
    fsStatus.className = 'fullScreenSupported';

    // handle button click
    fsButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        window.fullScreenApi.requestFullScreen(fsElement);
    }, true);

    fsElement.addEventListener(fullScreenApi.fullScreenEventName, function() {
        if (fullScreenApi.isFullScreen()) {
            fsStatus.innerHTML = 'Whoa, you went fullscreen';
        } else {
            fsStatus.innerHTML = 'Back to normal';
        }
    }, true);

} else {
    fsStatus.innerHTML = 'SORRY: Your browser does not support FullScreen';
}
```

to this:

```
var container = document.getElementById('canvas'),
fsButton = document.getElementById('fsbutton');

if (window.fullScreenApi.supportsFullScreen) { // fullscreen supported
    fsButton.style.display = 'block';

    container.addEventListener(fullScreenApi.fullScreenEventName, function() {
        fsButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (fullScreenApi.isFullScreen()) { // fullscreen is on
                window.fullScreenApi.CancelFullScreen( container );
                fsButton.className = 'fs-off';
            } else { // fullscreen is off
                window.fullScreenApi.requestFullScreen( container );
                container.style.width = "100%";
                container.style.height = "100%";
                fsButton.className = 'fs-on';
            }
        }, true)

    }, true);

} else {
    // no fullscreen support - do nothing
}
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't nest fsButton `click` event listener into fullScreenApi's event listener because it won't work until `container` goes fullscreen. fsButton's `click` is responsible for going fullscreen, event listener is being attached **after** going fullscreen so the action will never happen.

Here's a modified version of the code which should suit your needs:

```
var fsButton = document.getElementById('fsbutton'),
    container = document.getElementById('canvas');


if (window.fullScreenApi.supportsFullScreen) {
    fsButton.style.display = 'block';

    fsButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (fsButton.className == 'fs-off') {
            window.fullScreenApi.requestFullScreen(container);
        } else {
            window.fullScreenApi.cancelFullScreen(container);
        }
    }, true);

    container.addEventListener(fullScreenApi.fullScreenEventName, function() {
        if (fullScreenApi.isFullScreen()) {
            container.style.width = container.style.height = '100%';
            fsButton.className = 'fs-on';
        } else {
            fsButton.className = 'fs-off';
        }
    }, true);
} else {
    // no fullscreen support - do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other problem you'll have is that Mozilla wants you to listen to the `fullscreenchange` event on the `document` element, not the element that is going fullscreen.

```
// which object can handle a fullscreen event
var fullscreenObj = (fullScreenApi.fullScreenEventName.indexOf('moz') > -1 : document : container;

fullscreenObj.addEventListener(fullScreenApi.fullScreenEventName, function() {
    if (fullScreenApi.isFullScreen()) {
        container.style.width = container.style.height = '100%';
        fsButton.className = 'fs-on';
    } else {
        fsButton.className = 'fs-off';
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: Thanks but FS button has disappeared now. Might be a missing bracket in the `fullscreenObj` variable?

Comment: Nope, it was the `?`. So with `var fullscreenObj = fullScreenApi.fullScreenEventName.indexOf('moz') > -1 ? document : container;` it works like a charm. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise using something like https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/

This wraps most of the browser quirks in a cleaner interface.